# How can I determine pacing based on a value in my dataframe if its rank is volatile to change?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below I have an example dataframe:

| Rank | Color | Mentions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Green | 40102 |
| 2 | Red | 30231 |
| 3 | Blue | 30111 |
| 4 | Yellow | 29844 |
| 5 | Orange | 13944 |

Essentially, I want to know the pacing with the color Red.

Example: Red is 32% behind the most mentioned color.

I could just do:

df.loc[(df['Color'] == 'Green')].iloc[0][1] to get the 40,102 value and df.loc[(df['Color'] == 'Red')].iloc[0][1] to get the 30,231 value - to just compute it from there.

I am tracking Red every week, so if they become number one, I would say they are pacing % ahead of whoever is in second.

But since the rank changes on a weekly basis, how can I determine the mentions value of who is second behind Red if they were to be #1, or how far behind to whoever is #1 in mentions?

I'm trying to automate this so that I wouldn't have to adjust the loc formulas every week. Is there a method or formula to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not just sort the array and then use if test if red is number one or not

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['Mentions']).reset_index(drop=True)
if df.Color.iloc[0] == 'Red':
    #enter logic for case Red is nomber on
    red_value = df.Mentions.iloc[0]
    sec_color = df.Mentions.iloc[1]
else:
    #do logic for case Red is not number one
    first_place =df.Mentions.iloc[0]
    red_value = df.loc[(df['Color'] == 'Red')].iloc[0][1]
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you!